# OpenSL ES on Android with SL_ANDROID_STREAM_VOICE. Mic input is extremely low

Tags: android, android-ndk, volume, opensl

I am using OpenSL ES and SL_ANDROID_STREAM_VOICE to route audio in native Android app to the ear (phone) speaker instead of the main speaker.  The output to the ear speaker works fine, but now the audio input recording is extremely soft.  Is there any way to boost or reconfigure the mic in this situation?  Either SDK or NDK through OpenSL ES is acceptable.

Thanks!